# How to parse and interpret "Ну и досталось же ему от моей сестры!"?

Tags: значения, идиомы

> Ну и досталось же ему от моей сестры!

They are talking about a ladykiller trying to seduce a girl.

I can't make head nor tail of the meaning of this sentence. I wonder if "dative + достаться + от" makes up a set expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Достаться + object in Dative` means `to be received by` (usually in the context of distribution among a group of people) or `to accrue to`, e.g.

> Нашему атлету досталась бронзовая медаль - A bronze medal was received by our athlete

In the idiom, with the addition of preposition `от`, it means being on the *receiving* end of someone else's rage or violence.

This is again an impersonal construction, that which is *received* is only implied.

`ну и` here is an intensifying cluster expressing enthusiasm, cheer and a kind of post factum encouragement.

Comment: "**Ну и** досталось **же** ему от моей сестры!" vs "**Но и** досталось **же** ему от моей сестры!" I just noticed something interesting. In the former, "Ну и" as a whole serves as an *independent* intensifier, while in the latter, "и" places emphasis on the following verb "досталось". Although they are emphasised in a different manner, I wonder if they ultimately mean the same? Or do you detect any difference in level of intensity?

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens `но` is never, dare i to say, an intensifying particle, it's an adversative conjunction which introduces reservation or contrast to the previous statement, "Но и досталось же ему от моей сестры!" is an incorrect construction because `но`, `и` and `же` don't mix into a single semantic unit, they send conflicting messages

Comment: the possibilities are ""Но и досталось ему от моей сестры" and ""Но досталось же ему от моей сестры", the 1st one implies that besides something else the person was also trashed by the sister (But he also was...), the 2nd sounds like an objection to a claim that the person was spared by the sister (But wasn't he trashed...? or But he was trashed..., wasn't he?), neither of these sentences is exclamatory unlike the original

Comment: it's possible that the intensifiers `и` and `же` don't usually occur in the same construction, but since i haven't tried to analyze that in depth i won't vouch for accuracy of this assumption

Answer (score 8):

In this case "досталось" is a short form of an idiom  **"достаться на орехи"** - *"got punished / got scolded"* depending on the context. The referred punishment is not too harsh, but palpable.

Assuming that the main character was verbally abused, the phrase can be interpreted as:

> Ну и досталось же ему от моей сестры! - *Well, he got totally scolded by my sister!*

The other forms of the idiom are:

- достаться на калачи
- получить на орехи
- Смотри, достанется! *(as a warning)*

Answer (score 0):

You could translate this as:

> He got quite an earful from my sister.

The intensifying part is achieved here by `quite`.